# Block IP Address, Query IP from database

Tags: php, mysql, ip-address

I have an PHP code that the function is to block IP Address.

```
include ("includes/_db_.php");
$query_ip = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM t_ip_address");
while ($data_ip = mysql_fetch_array($query_ip))
{

$valid_ips = $data_ip['ip_address'];

if (!in_array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],$valid_ips))
{
    echo '<div class="denied"><img src="images/stop.png"/><span class="titles">Access Denied</span><br><span class="content">Sorry you do not have authorized to access this page.</span></div>
        <div class="footer"><a href="../">Back to previous page</a></div>
        ';
        exit();
    }
    }
```

But facing problem now, the error is : **Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, string given in...**

Anyone have an suggestions ?

Comment: why don't you just create `select * from t_ip_address where ip = $ip` then just check row count

Comment: `$valid_ips` is not an array, it's a scalar variable that you're updating each time through the loop.

Comment: So, what I have to do ?

Comment: Create an array, and add $data_ip['ip_address'] to it each time through the loop. Beginner PHP stuff.

Comment: [`MySQL`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php) (`mysql_*` functions) extension is [***deprecated***](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php). I suggest to use [`MySQLi`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) (`mysqli_*` functions) or [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead.

Comment: just as long as you know ip !=person.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are better off searching the database for `$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]` and checking to see if
it returns anything.

```
$query_ip = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM t_ip_address where ip_address = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"])."'";
if (!mysql_fetch_array($query_ip)){
    echo '<div class="denied"><img src="images/stop.png"/><span class="titles">Access Denied</span><br><span class="content">Sorry you do not have authorized to access this page.          </span></div>
    <div class="footer"><a href="../">Back to previous page</a></div>
    ';
    exit();         
}
```

Comment: I believe `if(!mysql_fetch_array($query_ip))` should be `if (mysql_fetch_array($query_ip))`

Comment: @Raidenace The answer is correct. The DB contains the list of allowed IPs, so if the client IP isn't found it displays "not authorized".

Comment: @Barmar: Oh! I thought it was a blacklist, not a white list. That should be a pretty closed access list...